# How do I change the company logo

Tags: logo

Our company recently changed the logo design.  how do I update the home page. I've already changed it in our outgoing emails.

Answer (score 5):

This configuration is at CMS level but not in CiviCRM. You can update the logo through theme config.

**For Drupal**

```
1. Navigate to Appearance >> Settings and under Logo image setting upload the new image and save.
2. Clear Drupal cache( and sometimes browser cache).
```

**For Wordpress**

```
1. Here it depends on the theme you using. For most of the theme you can change the logo by navigating to Appearance >> Header. You will be redirected to page where you can update the logo.
2. Save the theme setting.
```

HTH

Pradeep